# Changing PHP Directives on Apache Server

Tags: apache, webserver, directive

I have an Apache web server, but by default display_errors is set to '0'

I can change that manually on my site with ini_set but I want this to effect all my sites, and not have to put that on every page.

How can I log into my server and change a directive?

Comment: For Linux/Unix servers, you'd have to have ssh access. On Windows, probably remote desktop. That or some kind of management console/administrative interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out you can SHH into the server, go to the root dir, and then open etc/php.ini and change "display_errors = Off" to "display_errors = On"

Answer (score 0):

On how to log in to your server and change the setting directly in the `php.ini`: Ask your hoster. Nobody else can help you with that. They often provide a page, where you can change *some* settings.

But you may change the setting via `.htaccess`

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

This is *only* recommended for development environments. Test your applications local and not on your live server.